Spring Boot ignores dashes in property names in YML files
I've run into a weird behavior of Spring Boot (3.1.3) when using - in property names. Here's the sample code:
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
  }
}

@SpringBootTest
class DemoApplicationTests {
  @Value("${application.jokeurl}")
  private String jokeUrl;
  @Value("${application.joke-url}")
  private String jokeDashUrl;

  @Test
  void contextLoads() {
      System.out.println(jokeUrl);
      System.out.println(jokeDashUrl);
  }
}

And here's my application.yml:
application:
  joke-url: url1 #pay attention to dash in property name

When I run the test it prints two lines into the console:
url1
url1

We see that Spring injects the same String into Values referencing in fact different properties, i.e. @Value("${application.jokeurl}") and @Value("${application.joke-url}").
Now if I add one more property into application.yml as
application:
  joke-url: url1 #pay attention to dash in property name
  jokeurl:  url2 #no dash in property name

the same test prints different lines:
url2
url2

Now we see that the property application.joke-url is ignored in favor of application.jokeurl and again injects the same String into Values referencing different properties.
So my question is whether this is a bug or expected behavior?

It is expected behavior. It also ignore CamelCase.

its intended behavior (relaxed binding of properties for kebab case). See the documentation as follows: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/reference/features/external-config.html#features.external-config.files.property-placeholders, though I m not too sure why the ${application.joke-url} which picks up both jokeurl and joke-url doesn't choose joke-url over jokeurl due to exact match

Ok, I found out why. How relaxed binding works is to remove all special characters and then convert to lowercase, so joke-url == jokeurl source: spring boot wiki

@pebbleunit I guess then Spring Boot should issue a warning for joke-url and jokeurl are effectively the same

Spring Boot follows the concept of Relaxed Binding. The concept states:

Simple properties are bound by removing any special characters and
converting to lowercase.

In your case, application.joke-url property via Relaxed Binding becomes application.jokeurl. The value of joke-url property is replaced by jokeurl property because they are same property as per that concept.
That's why you are facing the issue.
FYI: Spring Boot will not throw any warnings/errors as this is an expected behavior.

Solution:
The trick is not use any special characters for simple properties.
Use camelcase. Change jokeurl to jokeUrl to fix your issue.
application.yml or application.yaml:
application:
  joke-url: url1
  jokeUrl:  url2

Updated DemoApplicationTests:
@SpringBootTest
class DemoApplicationTests {
  
  @Value("${application.jokeUrl}")
  private String jokeUrl;

  @Value("${application.joke-url}")
  private String jokeDashUrl;

  @Test
  void contextLoads() {
      System.out.println(jokeUrl);
      System.out.println(jokeDashUrl);
  }
}

Output :
url2
url1

Tested with JDK 21 and Spring Boot 3.1.4. It's working.

Writing about the warning I meant the case when there are two effectively same properties (my second case). To me this seems to be important as it's not clear which one Spring would pick up and inject

@SergeyTsypanov That's what I said in my answer. Relax binding doesn't give you option to make that difference between those properties. Spring Boot will consider both properties as same and replace the existing value with newer value if found.

What is the "newer value"? The property specified after the previous one?

@SergeyTsypanov Yes, the property after the previous one.
